# Infinity dots getting displaying while rendering list items

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to render nested list elements,

Below is the JSON structure,

```
listItems = {
  "text": "root",
  "children": [{
    "text": "Level 1",
    "children": [{
      "text": "Level 2",
      "children": [{
        "text": "Level 3",
        "children": [],
        "type": "unordered-list-item"
      }],
      "type": "unordered-list-item"
    }],
    "type": "unordered-list-item"
  }],
  "type": "unordered-list-item"
}
```

Below is my component html,

```
<ul *ngIf="listItems.type === 'unordered-list-item' && listItems.children.length > 0">
  <li *ngFor="let child of listItems.children">
    {{ child.text }}

    <bw-list *ngIf="child.type === 'unordered-list-item'" [listItem]="child"></bw-list>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If `children`is found it needs to repeat the component and render the children.

**Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() listItem: any;
  public listItems = {
    "text": "root",
    "children": [{
      "text": "Level 1",
      "children": [{
        "text": "Level 2",
        "children": [{
          "text": "Level 3",
          "children": [],
          "type": "unordered-list-item"
        }],
        "type": "unordered-list-item"
      }],
      "type": "unordered-list-item"
    }],
    "type": "unordered-list-item"
  };
}
```

Issue is it renders infinity dots. Please help

Link to project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-component-1smik4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your code. You forgot to reduce the length number? Maybe this can help you:

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div>
      Recursive Component
      <my-app [counter]="counter - 1" *ngIf="counter > 0"></my-app>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

    @Input() counter : number = 3;

}
```

Comment: I don't want to restrict to number, list can be n numbers

Comment: number should be the length of the list

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to app.component.html

```
<app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of listItems.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
```

See this code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-component-kpd6fm

Comment: I want to do with `<my-app>`

Comment: I don;t want to create another component for rendering the items